# Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline - setup build configuration programmatically

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I've created a script to initialize my Jenkins instance automatically using Multibranch Pipeline in a Groovy file

```
/* Adds a multibranch pipeline job to Jenkins */
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.plugins.git.extensions.impl.UserIdentity
import hudson.util.PersistedList
import jenkins.*
import jenkins.branch.*
import jenkins.model.*
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import jenkins.plugins.git.*
import jenkins.plugins.git.traits.*
import jenkins.scm.impl.trait.RegexSCMHeadFilterTrait
import com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.PeriodicFolderTrigger
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.*
// Create job
def env = System.getenv()
Jenkins jenkins = Jenkins.instance
String jobName = "Flow"
String jobScript = "flow/cicd/Jenkinsfile"
def job = jenkins.getItem(jobName)
// Create the folder if it doesn't exist
if (job == null) {
  job = jenkins.createProject(WorkflowMultiBranchProject.class, jobName)
}
job.getProjectFactory().setScriptPath(jobScript)
// Add git repository
String remote = env.CODE_COMMIT_URL
GitSCMSource gitSCMSource = new GitSCMSource(remote)
BranchSource branchSource = new BranchSource(gitSCMSource)
// Remove and replace?
PersistedList sources = job.getSourcesList()
sources.clear()
sources.add(branchSource)
// Add traits
String username = "Jenkins"
String email = "jenkins@email.com"
String regexExclude = "^(?!no-cicd).*"
def traits = []
traits.add(new BranchDiscoveryTrait())
traits.add(new LocalBranchTrait())
traits.add(new TagDiscoveryTrait())
traits.add(new UserIdentityTrait(new UserIdentity(username, email)))
traits.add(new RegexSCMHeadFilterTrait(regexExclude))
gitSCMSource.setTraits(traits)
// Periodic trigger
job.addTrigger(new PeriodicFolderTrigger("1m"))
```

I'd like to know if there is a way to remove Jenkinsfile from the build configuration and add it programmatically, using Groovy files too? For instance, instead of having `String jobScript = "flow/cicd/Jenkinsfile"` in Groovy file, I'd have

```
String buildConfiguration = "
pipeline {
  agent any
  tools {
    nodejs "nodejs"
  }
  environment { 
    CI = 'true'
  } 
  stages {
    stage("Checkout") {
      steps {
        checkout scm
        sh "git fetch --tags"
      }
    }
...
```

Currently, the only option I have is setting up a Jenkinsfile as shown below.

[image]

Comment: You might try this with Job DSL pretty sure you could do it that way.

Comment: @RichDuncan thank you! I have no idea how to Job DSL works, but I'll study it and verify if it helps me.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer or something to work? I am trying to do something similar. And, side note: You can actually do what you want in each branch of the build. So, if you go to the branch -> configure you'll see options of basically "inherit", "script" "from repo". BTW: This feature you're trying for is called "cloudbees core" if you buy it. And, it's pretty slick as it allows you to map finding a file in the repo, to a script being run - any script anywhere

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno I didn't find a way to make that works. I ended up using a Jenkinsfile.